# RXJS - Avoid inner subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Trying to hunt down the recipe i need but can't find it anywhere.

I have code that looks like this.

```
const Listeners = listen("data:join"); /* observable of people who want data */
const DataStream = stream("data"); /* observable of data */
```

How can i build a pipeline that:

- For each `person` that joins my listeners stream i subscribe them to the data stream.
- Each person that fires a `data:leave` event unsubscribes from the stream
- DataStream's long list of pipe operators under the hood only fire once NOT once for every person who joins.

EDIT: What is the equivilent to this in a memory safe way:

```
Listeners.subscribe((personListening) => {
     DataStream.subscribe((data) => personListening.send(data))
     // And until fromEvent(personListening, "data:leave") fires.
})
/* OR */
DataStream.subscribe((data) => {
    Listeners.subscribe((person) => {
        person.send(data);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure of your observables behavior, but on a general level you could use any of the RxJS higher-order mapping operators (like `switchMap`, `concatMap` etc. - differences [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)) to map from one observable to another. And use RxJS [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) operator to complete/unsubscribe from an observable based on another observable.

You could use the `takeUntil` to also close all open subscriptions when the component is closed.

Try the following

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, takeUntil, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

complete$ = new Subject<any>();

Listeners.pipe(
  switchMap((personListening) => {     // <-- switch to the `DataStream` observable
    return DataStream.pipe(
      tap((data) => personListening.send(data)),   // <-- call `send()` here
      takeUntil(fromEvent(personListening, 'data:leave'))
    );
  }),
  takeUntil(this.complete$)      // emit `complete$` on `ngOnDestroy` hook
).subscribe(
  _,                             // <-- do nothing on response
  (err) => console.log(err)      // <-- handle error
);

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.complete$.next();         // <-- close any open subscriptions
}
```

Comment: My problem was this is what i was doing but each listener would trigger all the inner pipes DataStream has under the hood each time and there was side-effects in there that i didn't want running twice.

Changed my inner code (under the hood of DataStream) now and it works great, this is actually my original solution you can see before my edits XD but will tick as answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna look on the skip and take operators of rxjs.

Example:

```
const data = interval(1000);

const start = timer(4500);
const end = timer(21800);

data.pipe(
  skipUntil(start),
  takeUntil(end),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

`data` is here a continous stream of emitions with a incremental number each second. `start` and `end` emit once after a defined time. In the console you will see a limited range of the data streamed.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ccdfif?file=index.ts

Comment: Added a edit sorry to make what i want more clear want a safe version of that last EDIT and i don't think this works, it would work if i only ever had a single person in listeners